# How to insert multiple inputs into the database using the power of PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, mysqli, foreach

I have a duplicate html form input now the problem here is I can't insert them all into the database. I was using foreach but the other fields cannot be inserted.

Here's my code:

```
<table><!---one name and date but has many products--->
    <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name_txt[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td><input type="date" name="date_txt[]" /></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td>Product</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="product_name_txt[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="description_txt[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Date Purchased</td>
        <td><input type="date" name="date_txt[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quantity_txt[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="price_txt[]" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><br><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Product</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="product_name_txt[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="description_txt[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Date Purchased</td>
        <td><input type="date" name="date_txt[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quantity_txt[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="price_txt[]" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><br><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="add" />
        <input type="reset" name="submit" value="clear" /></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Here's my php code for adding inserting into the database:

```
<?php   

if (isset($_POST['product_name_txt']))
    {      
        include 'db.php';

        foreach($_POST['product_name_txt'] as $row => $value){
                    $product=$_POST['product_name_txt'];
                    $description=$_POST['description_txt'];
                    $date=$_POST['date_txt'];                   
                    $quantity=$_POST['quantity_txt'];
                    $price=$_POST['price_txt'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO products (product_name,description,date,quantity,price)
                    VALUES ('$value','','','','')";

            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                    echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: \*sigh\* Obligatory, you have SQL injection vulnerabilities, comment. Props for not using `mysql_*` functions though.

Comment: use the `$row` index as your counter `$_POST['product_name_txt'][$row]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy, use foreach for take all data from post array.

```
if (isset($_POST['product_name_txt']))
{      
    include 'db.php';
    foreach($_POST['product_name_txt'] as $row => $value){          
                $product=$_POST['product_name_txt'][$row];
                $description=$_POST['description_txt'][$row];
                $date=$_POST['date_txt'][$row];         
                $quantity=$_POST['quantity_txt'][$row];
                $price=$_POST['price_txt'][$row];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO products (product_name,description,date,quantity,price)
                VALUES ('$value','','','','')";

        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about if I add the name and that name has many products or medicine. please look at my edited post above. For example I input the name Bill Gates then I input the products etc. The result would be like this: `Bill Gates | Product 1` and the next table `Bill Gates | Product 2`

Comment: Both table name is same but add 2 different row in database.

Comment: Name : __________ Product 1 _____________ Product 2 ____________. The result is Name | Product1 and Name | Product2

Comment: yes both table name is same but add 2 different row in database. How can we actually do that with just an input?

Answer (score 1):

your db.php file should contain code like this

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("your_localhost", "your_username", "your_password", "your_database_name");
```

Now lets come to your HTML & php code. 
check my my code below.

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Product</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="product_name_txt[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="description_txt[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Date Purchased</td>
        <td><input type="date" name="date_txt[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quantity_txt[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="price_txt[]" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><br><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Product</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="product_name_txt[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="description_txt[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Date Purchased</td>
        <td><input type="date" name="date_txt[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quantity_txt[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="price_txt[]" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><br><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="add" />
        <input type="reset" name="submit" value="clear" /></td>
    </tr>

</table>
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'add'){

    if (isset($_POST['product_name_txt']))
    {      
        include 'db.php';

        foreach($_POST['product_name_txt'] as $row => $value){

                    $product=$_POST['product_name_txt'][$row];
                    $description=$_POST['description_txt'][$row];
                    $date=$_POST['date_txt'][$row];                   
                    $quantity=$_POST['quantity_txt'][$row];
                    $price=$_POST['price_txt'][$row];


                $sql = "INSERT INTO `products` (`product_name`, `description`, `date`, `quantity`, `price`) VALUES ('".$product."','".$description."','".$date."','".$quantity."','".$price."');";

            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                    echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

[image: Check my Output that Query got executed successfully]

Comment: one more suggestion for you .

rather than executing query in for loop or foreach loop you can use batch insert. 
In which you just have to store all the values in an array and put that array into an query so that it will insert all the rows in just a single query.

Comment: I have another question. How about if I add the name and that name has many products or medicine. please look at my edited post above. For example I input the name Bill Gates then I input the products etc. The result would be like this: `Bill Gates | Product 1` and the next table `Bill Gates | Product 1`.